# Javascript button text change before processing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I currently have a button which has the value "Submit". I would like this text to change to "Submitting" as soon at it is clicked. At the moments, I have this:

```
<input type="button" id=btnSub name="submitToeNICQ"  value="Submit" onclick="do_submission()">
<div id="results"> No submission has been performed yet</>
<script>  
function do_submission()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("btnSub");
    elem.value="Submitting";
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var request = "main.php?pid=21&submiteNICQ=yes " 
    xhReq.open("GET", request, false);  // send a request
    xhReq.send(null);
    document.getElementByID("results").innerHTML=xhReq.responseText;
}
</script>
```

I would like the text to change before the XMLHttpRequest is processed, so that the change is immediate for the user. The above code seems to only change the button text once the whole request has been completed (normally about 3 seconds after button press).

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't perform synchronous AJAX requests. They're specifically made for **asynchronous** requests:

```
function do_submission()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("btnSub");
    elem.value="Submitting";
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var request = "main.php?pid=21&submiteNICQ=yes " 

    // Removed third parameter (it's now 'true' by default)
    xhReq.open("GET", request);

    // Added callback function for handling different states
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhReq.status == 200 && xhReq.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementByID("results").innerHTML=xhReq.responseText;
      }  
    }; 
    xhReq.send(null);

}
```

Your current code waits for the request to complete before it can update any UI parts.

The code above fires the request asynchronously, so the function will end before the request has even completed and the browser has time for updating the UI.

jQuery:

```
function do_submission()
{
    $("#btnSub").val("Submitting");

    $.get("main.php?pid=21&submiteNICQ=yes", function (data) {
      $("#results").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Will mark as accepted answer as soon as I'm allowed to (have to wait 10 mins).

Comment: @Josh Do you use jQuery (you added a tag for it)? Using jQuery for AJAX really shortens your code.

Comment: No I don't use jQuery, I don't know much about it. Thanks for the advice though, I will look into it now.

Comment: @Josh Then don't add the 'jQuery' tag in the question ;) Anyway, I posted your code rewritten utilizing jQuery functions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Got rid of the jquery tag :)